# Is there a way to compile a solution from a unit test and fail the test if the compile fails?

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I want to overwrite the *Program.cs* file in a solution I have created for a test, and then compile that solution - as a unit test.

With our library we have in the designer that comes with it a button titled *Generate Code*. When you click that button it pops up with the code for a sample Program.cs file that calls our library specifically written for the template created in the designer.

We want to have a unit test that verifies that the code we created compiles. We're not testing that it runs, just that it compiles. So the thought is we create a project, replace the *Program.cs* file in the project, and then compile the project. Successful compile, the test passes. Compile fails, the test fails.

What's driving this is we had a mistake in the code where it had `"${name}.compile()"` instead of `$"{name}.compile()"` - and that will easily be found with this.

So, can it be done?

Comment: This would essentially just be a test of the C# compiler. Why would you want to do that? If it’s some sort of attempt at a poor man’s static code analyzer, you’d be better off just writing an actual static analyzer, which is really easy now a days thanks to Roslyn. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn879356.aspx